# Tortoise SVN doesn't show those green , red , yellow icons - Windows 2008

Tags: windows, tortoisesvn, windows-server-2008

Tortoise SVN doesn't show those green , red , yellow icons when the files changed that are under source control, I can see them in windows XP but not on Windows 2008. But when I right click and try to commit, it gives me a list of files that are changed. Any idea why/fix?

Comment: for me this work! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964627/tortoisesvn-icons-overlay-not-showing-after-updating-to-windows-10

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you recently upgrade TortoiseSVN from a previous version?  Do a repair installation to restore your icons.

There is another workaround to solve this problem if a repair installation doesn't fix the issue. See the **UPDATE** section of [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442099/tfs-power-tools-shell-extension-context-menu-quirky-and-tfs-icons-on-files-fo) on Stack Overflow for more details.  Here is a [MSDN blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/youhana/why-am-i-not-seeing-the-icon-overlays-in-shell-extensions-tfs-power-tools) explaining the problem in detail if you're curious.

Comment: I had exactly this issue with the release before last and a repair of the installation fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

This has been a pretty big problem for a variety of reasons.  These are all outlined in the TortoiseSVN FAQ.  Here are the relevant links:

- [After upgrading TortoiseSVN, all my icon overlays have disappeared](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#ovllostonupgrade)
- [The overlay icons appear, but not all of them!](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#ovlnotshowing)
- [The overlay icons appear, but not all of them!](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#ovlnotall)

As part of this, if you have recently installed another program that uses overlays (Mozy is one that comes to mind), you may see this problem as well.  Unfortunately, Windows has a (artificial?) limitation on the number of potential overlays that can be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try killing the TSVNCache.exe process and re-starting it.  Is your local SVN respotitory on the large side?  In a previous job we migrated from XP to Vista while using Tortoise and, with a fairly huge codebase (many files), we all found those icons to be somewhat unreliable as a rule.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I installed onto Windows server 2008 R2 which did not previously have any Tortoise installation. After a reboot, I could see the icons ok. Didn't need to repair the installation or anything else. Rebooting servers might not be a valid option for you, but in my case it was not an issue.

Comment: I have more info to add for a clean install on server 2008: The TSVNCache.exe process is not running after you install tortoise. Rebooting the server will get it going, or you could just run c:\program files\tortoisesvn\bin\TSVNCache.exe. As soon as you do that, the icons appear.

Answer (score 0):

I had this very same problem but I got it fixed. 
What you have to do is follow the steps below,

1. Open control panel> Windows Firewall.
2. On the top left corner click on the link "Allow an app or feature through Windows Firewall"
3. At the bottom there is a button "Allow another app". Click on that.
4. Look for "TortoiseIDiff" and select it.

Your ticks and crosses should appear now.

Comment: That seems irrelevant. TortoiseIDiff is a tool for comparing image files, it doesn't have anything to do with the icons that appear. It must have been something else that fixed the problem, which coincidentally happened around the time you changed this setting.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue.
But My folders were in the network drive.

There is an option in SVN that by default sets showing of overlay icons to 'fixed drive' folders only. So we need to tick mark 'Network drive' also.

I've done this by-
SVN Setting--> Icon Overlays --> Drive types --> Network drives (tick it)

So its better to have a check in this setting first!!

Answer (score 0):

When I upgrade from `TortoiseSVN-1.6.15.21042-x64-svn-1.6.16` to `TortoiseSVN-1.10.1.28295-x64-svn-1.10.2`, I had same problem on my local directories. But on context menu I noticed a new context menu `SVN Upgrade working copy`. I clicked on it and after a while I see right icons.

Answer (score 0):

Check out also this answer, this solved this issue for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32384880/2700065

In short: **TortoiseSVN > Settings**

There is a Tortoise setting that determines which **Drive Types** the icons are used with: **Drives A: and B:, Removable drives, Network drives, Fixed drives, CD-ROM, RAM drives, and Unknown drives.**

For me my drive was an NVME SSD which is marked by system as a removable one for some reason (facepalm).