# TFS Power Tools: Shell Extension : Context Menu Quirky and TFS Icons on Files/Folders missing

Tags: tfs, tfs-power-tools

I've used [TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) on a daily basis for several months.  I particularly depend on Windows Shell Extension.

For about a week now, two issues have come up:

---

## Issue 1

Every time I enter a directory under TFS control, I have to right-click twice to see the TFS context menu
[image]

---

## Issue 2

My pretty TFS Green indicators on files/folders are gone:

[image]

I've downloaded and reinstalled the Power Tools, but I still have these two issues.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

---

## **UPDATE**

Dave gave me the answer via link.  Just in case that link goes bad, here is the answer:

1. Open the registry
2. Go to : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer \ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers
3. Prefix any "Tfs" folder with numbers (“1TfsOverlayAdd” , “2TfsOverlayEdit” etc.).  This allows them to take priority over other icon overlays.
4. Restart the machine or kill explorer.exe and restart it

   [image]

As far as the delay issue is concerned, I'm not experiencing that this morning; which is odd.  I question that the solution for the overlay was also the solution for the right-clicking.

Everything's back to normal now so I am good to go.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The missing green icons can be explained [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youhana/archive/2012/01/09/why-am-i-not-seeing-the-icon-overlays-in-shell-extensions-tfs-power-tools.aspx). It is because Windows has a limit of overlay icons it supports. The details on how to fix it are in that blog post.

How long are you waiting after entering a folder before you perform the first Right Click? It sometimes takes a while for the `TfsComProviderSvr.exe` to check if the local folder is a workspace and register the shell extension.

Comment: Thanks @DaveShaw.  Based on that link, it looks like I experienced the problem after installing "Google Drive."  Glad there was a fix; I didn't realize how much I depended on those little icons till they were gone. :P

Comment: Also, I'm not having the delay issue this morning; despite having it over the past few days.  I did not test it before the registry change; but I can't imagine that being the fix.  I connect to TFS remotely so perhaps my connection improved?  idk...it's working now and that's what counts.