# Need to use Team Foundation client in Android Studio probable alternatives/workarounds?

Tags: android, tfs, android-studio

I have a scenario wherein. I need to use android studio as IDE and Team foundation Server as source control repository.

The problem is there is no plugin for TFS in android studio.
And there is no standalone client for TFS(Windows)

I tried using Tortoise SVN with SvnBridge to connect to TFS. But it does not work.It seems there is a bug in SVNBridge.

Any suggestions, how to get this working?

Thanks

Comment: https://gittf.codeplex.com/ can help, though still plugin is not available

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answering my own question:

There is no possible way to use TFS with android studio. We have to wait for AS 1.0 release. Then they might migrate all features of Intellij to AS. And then it might have TFS support.Still no confirmation.

Comment: Hello from the future! Android Studio is on 1.3. Is this possible yet?

Comment: HI future guy.. I did see some yogic meditation to browse future and found that there would be and AS 1.3 release  but it will still not have the TFS because the TFS comes on intelliJ paid version and Android Studio would continue to remain a freeware ! My suggestion to you would be to renunciate TFS if possible and move to more natural VCS such as git or bitbucket. Namaste!  @Ben C. R. Leggiero

Comment: Now you have [Visual Studio Team Services Plugin for Android Studio](https://java.visualstudio.com/Downloads/AndroidStudioPlugin/Index).

Answer (score 8):

There are a few solutions:

- If you are using Visual Studio Team Services (visualstudio.com) or TFS 2013 you can use git and any free git client you like.
- If you are running on Linux/Mac you can use the [Team Explorer Everywhere command line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg490833.aspx).
- If you are using Windows, installing Visual Studio will give you a ["tf" command line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). 
  If you are using an Express Edition (or don't have Visual Studio) you will need [Team Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30656) or even [Team Explorer Everywhere](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30661).
- You can also see if the [MSSCCI](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b5b5053e-af34-4fa3-9098-aaa3f3f007cd) providers integrate with Android Studio.

Comment: @user2103379 no problems, please feel free to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) or [up vote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) my answer to keep with the spirit of Stack Overflow.

Comment: The Team Explorer link that u pasted gives an ISO image of 103 MB which seems to install a visual studio instance to get a TFS client. If its true then it seems too much of an overkill.
The MSSCCI  link that u gave expect me to install any software from a list to in order to have a tfs client- so similar story.

Comment: Isnt there a simpler way of doing it - open source way for windows?

Comment: You can use [TEE](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30661) on Windows 7/8 if you really want to.

Comment: Team Explorer indeed uses Visual Studio Shell at it's base. It's the smalles TFS client for Windows available today, unless you want to use the Cross Platform Commandline (which is Java based). or Eclipse en TEE.

Answer (score 3):

I have Android Studio 0.8.9 and attempted to install the TFS Integration plugin via the Plugins dialog available on the Welcome display. After restart of the AS, the TFS Integration plugin is indeed listed but is highlighted in red! Under the Version Control node in the Settings dialog, there is no TFS listed. Therefore appears it is not supported at present.

Comment: I tried this, and got the same result. According to the JetBrains page, Red (under Settings->Plugins->[a plugin] indicates one of the following: (a) The plugin is incompatible with the installed version of IntelliJ IDEA, or (b) The plugin depends on another plugin which is disabled.  

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/plugins-2.html

Comment: It would be nice if the guys at JetBrains had brains to add an error message to show what's wrong instead of just having it marked red and forcing users to search for documentation.

Next best would be not to allow installing incompatible stuff. And best would be to actually make it work, since other VCSs are included already.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows you can use the [Visual Studio Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f):

> **Windows Shell Extensions** This tool provides integration with Windows Explorer and the common file dialogs. With this integration, you can perform many source control operations without having to run Visual Studio or a Team Foundation command-line too

Comment: Hi Eric
Does it support regular client activities like code check in/ check out? It looks like just a set of enhancements. The only software I get on installing it is 'Best Practice Analyzer' which seems to be an enhancement tool.

Comment: Have you tried right-clicking through Windows explorer on a folder that is mapped to your TFS instance? You should see all of the regular client activities such as checking in/out of files. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105909/tfs-power-tools-shell-extension-not-showing-in-windows-explorer-context#17156629 for an example.

Comment: You need the Team Explorer installation for the Shell Extensions to work.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin listed in Jetbrains plugins page. 
You may try [this](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4578?pr=phpStorm)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, which I was just able to do successfully for one of my projects:

First make sure you have Git installed on your machine, which you can download from the open source project site. After installing, configure your android studio settings under Version Control - Git to point to the Git.exe file.

Create a Git project on TFS web portal or Visual Studio Online (click the New link and for Version Control, change the default Team Foundation Version Control to Git).

Once you create the project, navigate to the CODE page where you will find a link under "To clone this repository in Git, use the following URL:" (message slightly different in earlier versions, but the ling is still there). This will be the link you will use in Android Studio. If you are using Visual Studio Online, you will need to create a secondary login to your project so Android Studio can login. Click on your name at the top-right of the window and the My Profile link. Select Security (or Credentials in older versions) and then Enable alternate authentication credentials and create a secondary login ID. If you're using a corporate TFS, try to connect as indicated below, but you may need a TFS admin to help with permissions if you don't have access.

Open Android Studio. Under the VCS menu or on the main load page, select Checkout from Version Control and then Git. Enter the link you found in the CODE page of your new visual studio project for the Git Repository URL. The Parent Directory should be your android studio projects folder. Enter the name you want to give the new directory where your project will be or use the default if it is not already used.

Click the Clone button to create the Git directory on your machine. It will ask you to login, where you will enter the new ID and password you created in your visual studio profile (if TFS, try your network login or whatever you use to get into the web portal). You can now start a new project from scratch (once it finishes the clone operation it will ask if you want to create a project; click yes if you do, no if you're going to import an existing project), or copy the existing files/projects into the new directory (you may need to get rid of any existing git folder) and do an Import of the project and commit the changes under the VCS menu. If there are no changes detected, you can try the Add to VCS operation in the VCS Operations Popup under the VCS menu. This will allow you to force commit and then Push to the server. Your files will then be uploaded to the project and viewable in the web portal.

To pull existing projects, do a checkout from version control (git), clone and choose no if asked to create a project. Once the project is cloned, import the project app folder (you may need to sync with gradle).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Java ALM Team has released TFVC Support (in preview) for android studio and IntelliJ

> **The initial functionality available for preview is:**
>
> - Checkout a TFVC repository from Team Services or Team Foundation Server 2015
> - View, add, and rollback local changes in your repository
> - Create, view, and edit your workspace
> - Checkin and update local files
> - Merge conflicts from updates

more info :

- [TFVC Support in Preview for Team Services Plugin for IntelliJ and Android Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/09/18/tfvc-support-in-preview-for-team-services-plugin-for-intellij-and-android-studio/#comment-180195)
- [TFVC Support (Preview)](http://java.visualstudio.com/Docs/tools/intelliJ#_tfvc-support-preview)