# Does "Team Explorer Everywhere" integrate with Android Studio?

Tags: tfs, android-studio, project-management

I need to manage a mobile project which will support both iOS and Android. The team foundation server is the common tool I use for project planning and work items management.

I know that Team Foundation Everywhere works on Mac OS and iOS developers can easily update their work items and associate it with changesets.

But android developers use Android Studio and I am not sure whether they are able to use the tool as there isn't any information in TFE specification or in Android Studio.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need to use Team Foundation client in Android Studio probable alternatives/workarounds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541341/need-to-use-team-foundation-client-in-android-studio-probable-alternatives-worka)

Comment: Unfortunately, Android Studio is not based on Eclipse, it is based on IntelliJ IDEA.  IntelliJ has its own TFS integration which mostly works, though I do not know if it is available in Android Studio (I suspect not).  Ultimately, the link that @KMoraz posted should be helpful.