# How to get latest or commit with TFS server from Windows Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, windows-8.1, windows-explorer

### My need

Currently I have to open Visual Studio to make a `get latest` or a `commit` pending changes.

I want to do that the same way with TortoiseSVN right in Windows Explorer.

### What I have tried

I made google research and comes down to using the tool called [TFS 2012 Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f)

Someone also mentioned about this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17156629/248616)

Though after installed, I got nothing working as espected. Wondering did I do wrong then...

I'm using Windows 8.1 and Visual Studio 2012 Web Express.

### Question

How should I do to install it properly and get it work after all then?

Comment: The Power Tools should give you integration in Windows Explorer. There is not Team Foundation Server right-click menu in Explorer? What options have you selected during installation?

Comment: Yeah. No TFS item appears in the context menu. I installed with default seting @Wouter de Kort

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that when you installed the power tools you enabled shell integration and then logged out/back in to active them, then you need to do a few things:

1. Do an initial 'get' from TFS using Visual Studio Team Explorer and make a note of your workspace folder.
2. In Windows Explorer, right click that workspace folder. You should see the context menu items appear.

Most people having trouble with the context menu appearing have forgotten that to log out and log back in, as Windows Explorer needs to be restarted to pick up the new shell extension.

Comment: I'll retry and back with you soon

Comment: I did a restart, did a `get latest` again and again and... Nothing works as usual :(

Comment: @NamGVU Can you have a look at the event log and see if anything is showing up in there? Just a thought, but it's also worth checking if you have other shell extensions, anti-virus or group policy settings that may be preventing the TFS extension from loading or displaying.

Comment: Event log I know how to check it - will do and back with you later on. About checking for other extension, program that prevent TFS, I have to say I don't know how to check. May you guide me?