# TFS integration into WIndows 10 File Explorer

Tags: version-control, tfs, integration, windows-10

when running windows 8.1 I had the windows explorer extension that allowed TFS 2013 integration.

After an upgrade to Windows 10 that has "made off" as the police would like to say.

Has anyone got this working and if they have what did they do?

Comment: Have you re-installed the TFS 2013 Power Tools?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have finally got to the bottom of this.  It turns out that you dont match the power tools to teh TFS version (even though they are TFS power tools), you match them to the Visual Studio version regardless of the TFS version.

So in my case I have visual studio 2015 and TFS 2013.  I need to install the power tools for TFS 2015.

Thanks for your help everyone

Comment: I have pretty popular blog post on exactly this topic: https://jessehouwing.net/tfs-power-tools-install-side-by-side/

Comment: Thanks jessehouwing

Answer (score 6):

Beginning with Visual Studio 2017, a new extension called [Microsoft Team Foundation Version Control Windows Shell Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-vcw.TfsShellExtention) has been published to the Visual Studio Marketplace.

The description says:

> This release requires a computer with Visual Studio 2017 and all of the Visual Studio system requirements. It supports all TFS Server versions that are supported by Visual Studio 2017:
>
> - Team Foundation Server 2018
> - Team Foundation Server 2017
> - Team Foundation Server 2015
> - Team Foundation Server 2013
> - Team Foundation Server 2012
> - Team Foundation Server 2010 SP1
> - Visual Studio Team Services

Answer (score 0):

Dave is correct that, you need to install [TFS 2013 Power Tool](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f) to use Windows Shell Extension.

Then you can get the extension in a local folder which is in a **TFVC mapped workspace folder**.

Comment: Hi Guys. I have just uninstalled the power tools, rebooted the computer, re-installed the power tools, rebooted the computer.  Im afraid TFS is still a distant memory.  Any more suggestions would be gratefully received.  Thanks for the help so far both.

Comment: @MagicWand, the Windows Shell Extension is only available in the workspace folder, so please have a double check that you're looking for it in the correct folder. In addition, please also check this link which discusses the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105909/shell-extension-not-showing-in-windows-explorer-context

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  This is definately installed and not working.  I have also found other things that mis-behave quite badly on Windows 10.  Due to time constraints and the need to do some actual work I have rolled back to windows 81 and all is well.  I plan to use a spare laptop to re-install Windows 10 and try again but for now this is as far as I can take it. Thanks again for your help.