# TFS Power Tools 2015 not showing in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

In Team Foundation Server (TFS) I would like to do source code operations (move, branch) on multiple files. In previous versions of Visual Studio the TFS Power Tools gave me that functionality via context menu in the Source Control Explorer. I recently upgraded to VS 2015. I installed the TFS Power Tools 2015 but I don't get the power tool items in the context menu. Yes, I uninstalled the previous version of Power Tools. Any advice?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105909/shell-extension-not-showing-in-windows-explorer-context

Comment: Did you try on another machine? Are you able to reproduce this issue on another machine?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the powertools you use is downloaded from https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1
2. Try to reinstall Visual Studio 2015, then close Visual Studio before you install powertools, and restart after installing.
3. As the issue can't be always reproduced, please also check article [Why am I not seeing the Icon Overlays in Shell Extensions TFS Power tools ?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/youhana/2012/01/09/why-am-i-not-seeing-the-icon-overlays-in-shell-extensions-tfs-power-tools/) and try the advice there.