# TFS options in Windows Explorer

Tags: tfs

How do I get the TFS options to appear in Windows Explorer?

I have the Power Tools installed and for a few of my projects I do have the TFS options available in Windows Explorer.

I have recently created a couple of new branches from my Main project, but these new branches do not have the TFS options when "Right Clicking" the folder from within Windows Explorer.

I have tried reinstalling Power Tools, but this has not fixed my issue.

Does anyone know how I can get the TFS options to appear for my new projects in Windows Explorer?

If it makes a difference to the answer: I am using VS2008 with Power Tools 2010.

I cannot use a newer version of VS.

Comment: Have your tried a 'force' get? In VS right-click the folder and select *Advanced*->*Get Specific Version...* and tick the two checkboxes. This will refresh the local source control information.

Comment: I have just tried getting the latest version again as you requested, but I still only have the options in Windows Explorer for my old projects and not my new one's.

Comment: Do you have a workspace mapped for them?

Comment: Yes I have a workspace mapped.

I can Check-In etc. from other avenues so there doen't appear to be an issue with the mapping or the location of the project; I just don't have the Windows Explorer options.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?  Did you give a try with my solution below ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Team Foundation Server Power Tools December 2011](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MartinWoodward.TeamFoundationServerPowerToolsDecember2011) in your environment. You could try this solution: Uninstalled the old TFS Power Tools ( listed with a "Microsoft Team Foundation Server" prefix and/or "Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server" in Control-Panel/Programs-and-Features ) and install a newer version.  Such as:

- Team Foundation Server 2012 RTM Power Tools.msi

You could also try to execute this file:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 201X Power
>   Tools\TfsComProviderSvr.exe

More detail ways please refer this similar question: [Shell Extension : Not showing in Windows Explorer context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105909/shell-extension-not-showing-in-windows-explorer-context)