# VS 2019/TFS Shell Extension: Not showing in Windows Context Menu

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2019, tfvc

(I did look at this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105909/shell-extension-not-showing-in-windows-explorer-context) but it is outdated for VS 2019)

I have VS 2019 Enterprise installed on my Windows 10 workstation.

I tried to install the latest version of [TFS Source Control Explorer Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HolanJan.TFSSourceControlExplorerExtension-13343&ssr=false#overview) but get an error that this cannot be installed with any of the currently installed products.

So is that tool no longer available with VS 2019?

Comment: Do you mean to shell extension for windows or source control explorer for VS? (your second link is for VS)

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk: hi, I mean Shell Extenstion for Windows

Comment: There is no support for this in VS 2019 :(, see my answer.

Comment: you can install team explorer 2015 and it should install.  It needs that older version of TF.exe to work it's not in the same path structure, the new installer goes to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VERSION\SKU\... while before it went into C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio xxx If i'm not mistaken.  have you tried downloading this package instead https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-vcw.TfsShellExtention

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To Visual Studio 2019 doesn't have support (yet) in [Microsoft Team Foundation Version Control Windows Shell Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-vcw.TfsShellExtention&ssr=false#overview).

You can see an issue about it [here](https://github.com/jawn/visualstudio2019-discuss/issues/5) and track the status in [this](https://twitter.com/youhanaNaseim/status/1117962415814082560) tweet.

According to Aug 13 to Microsoft does not have an update on this yet.

Answer (score 3):

It is available for VS2019 now:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-vcw.TfsShellExtentionVS2019