# Why does TFS Power Tools 2012 not recognise newly uncloaked project?

Tags: contextmenu, tfs-power-tools, cloaking

I have TFS Power Tools 2012 installed on my PC.

I recently uncloaked a project in TFS and performed a get operation to bring the project folder into my private workspace (using server-side for backwards compatability with VS2010).

Whilst in Visual Studio, there is no problem - I can check it out and check back in.

However, Power Tools does **not** recognise the new folder in windows explorer. In other words, all other projects have the green-arrow icon overlay, but this one doesn't. Right-clicking on the folder also does not bring up the TFS context menu.

Does anyone know what I may have neglected to do? I have tried deleting the folder and doing a "Get specific..." to bring it back in. Hell, I've even done a repair on TFS Power Tools and restarted; the behaviour remains unchanged.

---

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442099/tfs-power-tools-shell-extension-context-menu-quirky-and-tfs-icons-on-files-fo) is not my problem (the rest of my projects **do** show the icon overlay)...

Possible duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105909/tfs-power-tools-shell-extension-not-showing-in-windows-explorer-context?rq=1) maybe...

Comment: Just to be clear, you performed this action in Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: Nope, in 2010... hence the private server-side workspace. The server is TFS 2012 though, and I've been successfully using both VS2010 and VS2012 like this (separate workspaces of course)

Comment: Best practice is to match your TFS Power Tool and Visual Studio versions so that they share metadata files.  Otherwise you have to get the 2012 client to refresh your workspace information from the server.  Not sure when the explorer integration does that.  Can you connect with VS 2012 or run `tf workspaces` from a 2012 `tf.exe`?

Comment: I deleted the folder now and did a "get specific - latest - overwrite all" from inside VS2012. It made no difference; the problem is with power tools, not TFS itself

Comment: I have found the solution. I have two server-side workspaces (a private one for VS2010, and a public one for VS2012). When I uncloaked the project for my public workspace as well, it was suddenly recognised in both workspaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed Power Tools sometimes has conflicts with icon overlays, particularly when they compete with others (like SVN).

It can also conflict when you have multiple workspaces on your PC. As you mentioned, make sure the project is uncloaked in both workspaces.