# TFS - Power tools - How can I add graphics in folders or files

Tags: tfs, tfs-power-tools

I am using `tfs`. I am happy about all, but the thing is I am not getting any icons like `tortoise` svn do. how to make the icons to my folders/files.

here is `tfs` view :

[image]

And the tortoise view :

[image]

See the `commited` folders with `green tick` icons. but in the `tfs` there is nothing. how to update to `icons` version of `tfs`

**UPDATE**

**ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers Items**

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [TFS Power Tools: Shell Extension : Context Menu Quirky and TFS Icons on Files/Folders missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442099/tfs-power-tools-shell-extension-context-menu-quirky-and-tfs-icons-on-files-fo)

Comment: Do you get tfs commands if you right click checked in file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problema may be related to the Windows limitation of 15 file extension icons.

You can read more about this problem here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youhana/archive/2012/01/09/why-am-i-not-seeing-the-icon-overlays-in-shell-extensions-tfs-power-tools.aspx

They recommend you to:

> - Open the registry
> - Goto: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer \ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers`
> - Rename our icon overlays to *1TfsOverlayAdd* , *2TfsOverlayEdit* etc. to bump us up the list
> - Restart the machine or kill *explorer.exe* and restart it

*Note:*
As they say in the post, this is a hacky solution, because it will lead other entries to the end of the list, thus stop working

Comment: I renamed all folder as like your suggestion. But no icons updated. what is wrong here? do i need to install any other tools?

Comment: Did you have more than 15 entries in that folder?

Comment: I am not getting you.. in which folder are you asking? I nothing but re-named the folders.

Comment: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer \ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers` folder in `regedit`, do you have more than 15 entries?

Comment: Can you see the screen shot in the `update` section of my question?

Comment: I have more than 15 entries, because i have drop box. what is the fix  here?

Comment: Great, I see the screenshot, have you notice a blank space prefixing the `_AccExtIco1, 2, 3` and also `_DropBoxExt1,2,3...` ? That's the problem, remove those spaces