# TortoiseSVN icons overlay not showing after updating to Windows 10

Tags: tortoisesvn, windows-10

I had been using Windows 8 and TortoiseSVN icons have been displaying properly, but after installing Windows 10 I can no longer see the icons for the files/folder status.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/issues/2548

Comment: [This worked for me on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2052946)

Comment: Rebooting my Win10 machine was all I needed to do (in my case).

Comment: .cmd skript worked for me on win10 https://stackoverflow.com/a/41727983/1650038

Comment: Note: You don't need to reboot your machine, just killl and restart Explorer from the Task Manager.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Had same issue, and was solved by running `regedit`, erasing some entries in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers` and restarting.
Deleting OneDrive1... enties was not permited, but I had some from Google Drive. 
You can also make a bakup by double-clicking in the registry directory and doing an "Export" to a file.

On Windows 10, most of the entries are used by OneDrive and you won't have permission to remove them. In order to do so, right click on the entry (Example: "OneDrive1", then click "Advanced", then click the link labled "Change" at the very top next to "Owner". This lets you change the owner. Type in your username and hit OK. Now give yourself "Full Control" and then apply it. Now you should be able to delete or rename it.

Comment: I sort of followed this answer, except that I renamed the Tortoise icons to start with 1, 2, 3,...etc in order to let them show at the top

Comment: There is an option that takes you to that registry in _Settings -> Icon Overlays -> Overlay Handlers -> Start registry editor_. At least in version 1.9.1

Comment: It may work, but not correct, Please check the solution provided by Kelly Carter.

Comment: Ha-ha-ha! Microsoft changed OneDrive ones to start with a space! I have added a space in front of each _already numbered_ Tortoise node as well. I feel this is not the end of it.

Comment: I just uninstalled Dropbox (which I have no need for) which was taking up icon slots and, lo and behold, my TortoiseSVN icons are back. (That's all I needed to do.)
Edit: well, most of them - but the plus icon for new, unversioned files is still missing. The main ones (green tick and red exclamation mark) are there

Comment: I ran out of time to re-edit my previous comment - just remove my edit: I forgot you have to add the unversioned files before the blue plus sign appears - which it does. :)

Comment: Now OneDrive and DropBox are prepending with even more spaces. It's the space race all over again...

Comment: I backed up my Google Drive keys just in case, deleted them, restarted my File Explorer and it worked! Tortoise overlays, finally!

Comment: Why deleting `OnedriveX` entries is not permitted?

Comment: Google drive only added 3 entries.  TortoiseSVN added 9.  Since I didn't really need OneDrive, it was easier to uninstall it than to find a way to keep it at the bottom of the list.

Comment: This is a good answer and an effective one but @cyx 's answer should be marked correct. as deleting keys impacts other applications

Comment: Got my fix... From Settings->Overlay Handlers->Start Registry Editor. I added 3 more spaces to the TortoiseSVN registry folder names so they appear at the top and restarted computer. I swear this belongs on r/softwaregore

Answer (score 148):

Run `regedit.exe` and go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers`.

[image: Registry editor shot]

As in current recommended answer mentioned, you need to sort the entries of the overlay identifiers in the registry. I haven't deleted those OneDrive or GoogleDrive entries but renamed all Tortoise Folders by adding 3 spaces to bring them on top. Just restart and even with Tortoise SVN client 1.7.9 you'll see your SVN overlay icons under Windows 10 again.

Comment: It may work, but not correct, Please check the solution provided by Kelly Carter.

Comment: What a ridiculous mess. On my machine, OneDrive, SkyDrive keys all have a space in front of the name, trumping svn which only had numbers. So I add two spaces. Next version, OneDrive will have three spaces. In a few more versions, we'll fall of the east edge of the screen.
[Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411336/shelliconoverlayidentifiers-why-so-few)'s some background info.

Comment: Yes, my machine has Dropbox entries above OneDrive, with even more spaces. Seems the shell overlay wars have begun.

Comment: @adabyron where do I find these keys with spaces? In regedit, if I click on one of the folders under ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers (e.g. Tortoise1Normal) all I see is the (Default) key, type REG_SZ and the data is a UUID.

Comment: @Groo I see adabyron's post was a year ago, so can you help with my question above, please? (Can't flag more than one user, it seems.) EDIT: Ok scrub that! It seems people are referring to the folder names, not the actual keys. If I right click and rename I can see the spaces. Can't tell with proportional fonts!

Comment: @JeffG: great, glad that you found the solution. The reason is that Windows only takes first 15 entries inside `ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers` into account and ignores everything else, so now every application is trying to beat the system by inserting spaces to get a higher "alphabetical" rank.

Comment: This helps in solving my problem also. I was not having admin rights in my computer. But still i was able to resolve svn issue using this solution.

Comment: After the other answers failed to resolve my issue, I tried this and it worked.  Except that I had to add *5* spaces in from of the Tortoise keys to get them ahead of OneDrive.  Insanity!

Comment: @Groo Where did you find that Windows only takes into account the first 15? Is there a way to increase that limit?

Comment: This answer should be the one accepted.

Comment: Just a note that it now requires TEN SPACES to get Tortoise above OneDrive.  And I had to change the permissions of the parent ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers to be allowed to do so.  I've tried uninstalling OneDrive in the past, but it seems to reinstall with Windows updates, so not even that works.

Answer (score 36):

You can go to:

```
Tortoise Settings > Icon Overlays -> Overlay Handlers
```

[image: Screenshot]

and uncheck all checkboxes, apply, then reactivate them and apply.

This will do the same thing in the registry but not manually.

Otherwise you can open the registry with the button below, and move up the keys, appending some spaces before the name.

Comment: Worked for me.  Needed to reboot but after that the overlays were there

Comment: It did not work for me on Win 10 Pro. :-/ Did you have to reboot twice: Once after unchecking the checkboxes, and once after checking them back on?

Comment: I had to start the "Settings" program as administrator. Finally I just restarted the Explorer in taskmanager and it worked again.

Comment: I had to uninstall drop box before any of these registry fixes would work. Just a heads up for others.

Comment: Best solution for me.

Answer (score 35):

I fixed my problems with TortoiseSVN icons not showing up in Windows 10, for the special case where my repository was on a removable drive.

There is a Tortoise setting that determines which **Drive Types** the icons are used with: **Drives `A:` and `B:`, Removable drives, Network drives, Fixed drives, CD-ROM, RAM drives, and Unknown drives**.

It was NOT a problem with the naming of the icon overlays in the Windows Registry.

The names were automatically prefixed with "1", "2", etc.

to force them (in my computer) alphabetically at the top of the list just before the OneDrive icons.

So, all of the icons were within the top 15. To get to the Tortoise settings, right click on Desktop or a folder and then choose **TortoiseSVN > Settings**.

In Settings, choose **Icon Overlays**. There'll you find the **Drive Types** settings.

Comment: It is not just 1,2 and 3. there are spaces before names too. in any case they should stand on top of the list

Comment: YES! Checking "Removable drives" and "Network drives" was what I needed to do.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not solve the issue for me on Windows 10 with TortoiseSVN 1.9.4 and TortoiseGIT 2.3.0.0. :-/

Comment: Though I did not have much hope, for some reason checking network and removable drives fixed my problem (though my files are on a fixed drive) on windows 10 v1607-14393.447 with tortoise svn 1.9.4 27285; both are x64.

Comment: Thanks, ran into this issue today with TortoiseGIT. Checking the necessary boxes under the Drive Types area was the solution for me.

Comment: _"Show excluded root folders as normal"_ is also required together as _"Network drives"_ if you have a shared folder inside your VM guest.

Answer (score 24):

Windows explorer allots 15 custom overlay icons (Windows reserves 4, so effectively only **[11 overlay icons](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3106961/registered-icon-overlay-handlers-aren-t-used-by-windows-shell)**) - they are shared between multiple applications (Google drive, One drive, Tortoise SVN). If you have multiple applications installed - the first ones in list will display their icons, rest of applications won’t.

Problem is described deeper in: https://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#ovlnotall.

Open registry editor in:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers`

Rename icons which are not important to you to start from ‘z_’ prefix (will be last in list, will not be used after that).

[image: regedit snapshoot]

Windows restart might be needed, as just restart explorer does not work. But in my case icons appeared to be correct after some time. (10-20 minutes ?).

Comment: Unbelievable that this limit was the reason for the issues with my icons :O

Comment: Thank you very much! A strange limitation..

Comment: I used the TortoiseSVN Settings / Icon Overlays / Overlay Handlers and then the button to Start Registry Editor which took me directly to the entries that needed editing. I found at the top of the list were a set of entries for Google Drive which I had recently installed - I then renamed each of those and prefixed them with a "1" to push them further down the list, then used Task Manager to restart Windows Explorer and that did the trick. Windows 10.

I did try all of the other solutions involving the SVN Settings dialog but they didn't work for me.

Answer (score 14):

[TortoiseSVN 1.9.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisesvn/files/1.9.1/) will work around the issue by renaming the Overlay Icons (starting with 2 spaces) to [make sure they are loaded before the OneDrive icons](http://sourceforge.net/p/tortoisesvn/code/26717/).

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot upgrade to TortoiseSVN 1.9, because our servers are still running svn-1.6. Any ideas how to solve this with TortoiseSVN 1.8?

Comment: I tried re-installing ToortoiseSVN 1.9.4, and unfortunately, this did not solve the issue for me on Windows 10 (with TortoiseSVN 1.9.4 and TortoiseGIT 2.3.0.0). :-/

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisBeauchamp count the number of registered overlays and delete some if you have more than 15

Comment: Irritatingly, it now seems that Dropbox is inserting *3* spaces before the names of *its* Overlay Icon Handlers.... so I needed to renamed my TortoiseSVN Icon Handlers to have *4* spaces at the front. This is just a war of attrition :(

Comment: @JonPawley say "thanks" to Microsoft for not increasing the ugly limit. Instead of making the core of Windows better, they now change the color of BSOD to green. Here you see their priorities.

Comment: Like Jon Pawley said, others have adopted this strategy as well now. On my system, the Google drive and OneDrive entries all started with 2 spaces :(

Comment: @Moolie yes I already saw this. Dropbox now also uses 3 spaces. send feedback to MS via feedback hub app.

Answer (score 10):

I would recommend you to change Status cache of the Overlays.

`Settings -> Icon Overlays -> Status cache`

Maybe this would help to reinitialise the cache.

[image]

Be sure touse the latest version of Tortoise.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work for me. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not solve the issue for me on Windows 10 with TortoiseSVN 1.9.4 and TortoiseGIT 2.3.0.0. :-/

Comment: I tried several other combinations but it didn't work but this suggestion fixed my issue.

Comment: @madan nice :-)

Answer (score 7):

**Check your monitor scaling**.

My problem turned out to be this:

*It turned out to be different DPI-scaling on the primary and secondary monitor. When the secondary monitor was set to 125% (same as the primary monitor) the icons appeared again.*

[Answer actually provided by User3163 posting on SuperUser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/968212/tortoisesvn-shell-overlays-only-showing-for-medium-and-large-icons-in-explorer?rq=1)

Comment: This was the case for me. I tried all the other steps listed in other answers including changing the registry. None of them worked for me.However, I have a dual external monitors running at native resolution while my internal display was running at 125% (easier on my eyes). It was only after changing my internal display to 100% that the icon overlays showed for me. I am using TortoiseGit v2.2.0.0 on Windows 10. Way to go Microsoft ... still have not DPI scaling to work correctly. Thanks for the answer @BenButzer!

Comment: This answer needs more visibility!  tried everything and it turned out to be DPI.

Comment: In my case it did not matter if the scales were the same or different; what mattered was the scale itself.  For example, 150% on one monitor was okay on that monitor, but 100% on the other was not. If I moved a window showing icons from the 150% monitor to the 100% monitor, the icons would disappear.  Excellent design by someone...NOT.

Answer (score 5):

Tortoise Settings > Icon Overlays -> Overlay Handlers -> Start registry editor

**1.** Rename icon name :By adding a space(s) at the beginning of the file's name and
then press F5 until it goes to top .
example: "  Tortoise1Normal" (in default 2 spaces included)⇒ "   Tortoise1Normal" (3 spaces)

**2.** Restart explorer in Task manager

[Registry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LU5UN.png)

Answer (score 4):

Please upgrade your the Tortoise SVN to the latest one.. 
I would recommend you to change your Settings [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWPe6.png)

```
Settings -> Icon Overlays -> Status cache
```

make it as Shell and Apply

Now reboot your machine to reflect the chnages.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem as OP.  Installing version 1.9.2 resolved the issue without any tweak.

Comment: In my case I used 1.9.3.

Comment: After upgrading from 1.7.7. to 1.9.4, I had to right-click on the folders in Explorer that were mapped to SVN and choose **SVN Upgrade working copy**. Only after allowing the upgrade "to the new 1.8 format" did the icon overlays re-appear.

Comment: And now after wiping the hard drive, re-installing Windows 10, then re-installing TortoiseSVN 1.9.2. again the icons wouldn't re-appear. I had to rename the hidden folders from _svn to .svn. It seems there may have been an override in place before (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/21636584/550712)

Answer (score 3):

The following steps worked for me:

1. TortoiseSVN -> Settings -> IconOverlays -> Icon Set
2. Choose "Win10" icon set
3. Restart computer.

Comment: This has no effect with `TortoiseSVN-1.9.5.27581-x64` and Microsoft Windows `[Version 10.0.14393]' I'm afraid.

Comment: I can also confirm this has no effect on the latest SVN.

Comment: Worked for me, try Refresh Shell Overlays under clean-up if it doesn't work at first.

Comment: Worked for me as well with Tortoise SVN 1.14.0

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using Windows 10, there's a request in Feedback Hub to get Microsoft to fix this issue. If you'd like to add a +1 to have it fixed, here's a link: https://aka.ms/Cryalp.

The link only works on Windows 10 as it needs to open Feedback Hub to get to the suggestion. The link was generated using the "Share" feature in Feedback Hub and aka.ms is an internal link shortening service used by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

svn upgrade the working copy. In my case, Jenkins never did a complete fresh checkout and hence the working copy was out of date.

Comment: This should be a comment I think.

Answer (score 1):

I did all of the above and nothing worked. The overlay icons were appearing in Explorer but not in Total Commander.

Eventually what solved the issue for me was that I discovered a command in Total Commander that refreshed the Overlay Icons. To access it, right click on the toolbar and click on "Change...", and add "cm_SwitchOverlayIcons" as shown in the image below.

After adding the command icon to the toolbar, I click it once, and the overlay icon of TortoiseSVN appeared!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was using **Subversion 1.7.x** and installing the version 1.9.1 or modifying the registry entries did not solve this issue of icon overlays.

In my case, after using ***SVN upgrade working copy*** the icon overlays for the upgraded project appeared.

In conclusion, old projects using Subversion 1.7.x do not show icons and projects using Subversion 1.9.x do (under Windows 10).

Tip: there is a button that takes you to the registry in *Settings -> Icon Overlays -> Overlay Handlers -> Start registry editor*. At least in version 1.9.1

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all my onedrive keys, installed latest preview etc and finally realized that the icons were working all along for some explorer directory views and not others.

In other words, medium, large, extra large, and tiles, but not list or detail.  Since I don't want to learn all about how that works, I am just viewing my work directories as tiles for now.

Answer (score 0):

As others have indicated, the overlay icon registry area is congested. Here is a powershell script that allows you to dump all the overlays in the registry to a file, then after you edit the file to prioritize your overlays the way you want, you can import them back in and protect them against further modifications from other programs running under SYSTEM.

https://github.com/polachz/OverlayIconFix

Answer (score 0):

If you are using other version control software, it may be in conflict. In my case, uninstalling Plastic SCM restored Tortoise SVN icons.

Answer (score 0):

Checking "Removable drives" and "Network drives" worked for me.