# Is there a Fix for TortiseSVN Overlay Icons on Windows

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

Sometime today the TortiseSVN overlay icons disappeared on my Windows 10 PC.  A quick google search shows many, many, many instances of this occuring over the past few years from Windows 7 up to recent Windows 10.

By and large the suggestions fall into two groups.  Various manipulations that don't work any more and manually hacking the registery with `RegEdit` to delete some other icons.  In addition there are many examples of this issue for Tortisehg and TortiseGit.

So we are on the same page, these are the Tortise and Windows version giving me grief today.  It is high time we found a way to FIX this problem instead of having to muck-about in inside the registery.  Uninstalling TortiseSVN and re-installing doesn't work for me.

That in itself points to there being a fundemental problem *imho*.  If TortiseSVN was working Monday, and not working if I install it on Wednesday -- The icon management underlying the tool appears to be fautly.

Anyway, I'm hoping someone wiser can suggest or point us to a tool or script or patch that will actually Resolve the issue.
The problem is exaccerbated by windows because it makes OneDrive some kind of protected species and I can't move or rename these icons (at least not yet).

TortiseSVN

- TortoiseSVN-1.9.5.27581-x64-svn-1.9.5.msi

Windows 10

- Version 10.0.14393

related:

- [TortoiseSVN icons overlay not showing after updating to Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964627/)
- https://superuser.com/questions/968212/
- [TortoiseSVN icons not showing up under Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057734/)

Comment: I gave up long time ago worrying about this.

Comment: BTW: The **Cleanup** command has [a checkbox to refresh the Shell overlays](http://i.imgur.com/1nkmEMg.png).

Comment: We often (with older Windows versions) see the icon overlays go out of date (e.g., showing red bubbles after everything has been committed).  To reinforce what Uwe said above, I find the Cleanup command reconciles those differences.  Maybe it'll bring back your icons.  But I'll add this:  DON'T RELY ON THEM!  They're inaccurate far too often.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TortoiseSVN icons not showing up under Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057734/tortoisesvn-icons-not-showing-up-under-windows-7)

Comment: I asked my my Microsoft contacts and they have no plans to increase the ugly 15 limit, they even want to kill the overlay icons completely.  so delete/rename entry you don't care.

Comment: @UweKeim, yes and that is always my first action -- It no longer works with my Windows 10.  I have completely reinstalled TortiseSVN, no good.

Comment: @magicandre1981 -- Can Not be a duplicate because Tortise say that the Windows 7 & 8 icon problem is `fixed` with TortiseSVN 1.9.  Also, it is recent.  Monday or Tuesday's Windows update ... grrr. (I cite that question in the text actually).

Comment: it is a DUP, because you both hit the ugly 15 overlay limit of Windows!

Comment: @magicandre1981 -- That's somewhat arbitrary, in fact the question is about a Fix, the question for Windows 7 is looking for any kind of workaround.  From the conversation there and here the answers are hacks.  I'm looking for a tool or some kind of patch code update -- May be no one has invented something yet ... That doesn't negate the expressed intention.

Comment: there IS NO patch for this, no matter how often users ask this. Submit it in feedback hub and hope it gets enough upvotes so that MS fixes it in a newer Win10 build

Comment: here is some background: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775227.aspx, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761389%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Image_Overlays and here you see the 15 overlay limit is a ImageList limitation in windows

Comment: I prefer a can do attitude -- a fix is possible, unfortunately seems there is not much interest in creating one.

Comment: I gave it up. submit it via feedback hub, share this link (facebook twitter) to get a lot of people to vote on it.

Answer (score 28):

> It is high time we found a way to FIX this problem instead of having to muck-about in inside the registery.

What is attempted in my take for this problem was to automate the registry manipulation; uses the hack everyone seems to be using (prepending spaces before overlay entries) and even offers to restart Windows Explorer afterwards:

1. Go to [TortoiseSVN-FixIconOverlays[RunAsAdministrator].cmd](https://gist.github.com/HelderMagalhaes/37ca7bbdba2b693006c46df1d8481705)
2. Save the file
3. Run as administrator (as hinted)
4. Allow the tool to restart Windows Explorer for changes to be effective immediately

> Uninstalling TortiseSVN and re-installing doesn't work for me.

This only solves some forms of registry corruption, not what's already being suggested in other comments: that the most common cause for such problem is the overlay limit being hit.

**Bonus**: it should be fairly straight-forward to modify the tool for similar usages: for example, making sure `GoogleDrive` icons are always visible.

**Bonus 2**: the script (referred in step 1) actually searches for the broader term "Tortoise", so it can be used **out-of-the-box** to repair other *TortoiseOverlays*-based software such as `TortoiseGit`, `TortoiseHg`, `TortoiseBzr` or `TortoiseCVS`.

Comment: It was a great solution, it seems that is common for problems to appear in the registry

Comment: Great!! That worked for me. Thanks!! It solve the SVN icons, but now, dropbox icons does not work, :o

Comment: @DanielSilva: that's because there **is** a limit! ;-)
As stated in item 2 of linked script "references":
[Windows can only show a limited number of Overlay Icons (15 total, 11 after what Windows uses)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1228918/1111895)

Answer (score 3):

All the methods I could find using Google, did not work, but I fixed it using this method:

Open `Regedit`and go to this location:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers`

This is where all overlay icons are defined, and it also defines the order they are applied. The problem is that Windows only uses the first 11 of them (Windows allots 15 overlay icon handlers, but Windows reserves 4, so effectively only **[11 overlay icons are used](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3106961/registered-icon-overlay-handlers-aren-t-used-by-windows-shell)**), and Dropbox uses 10 of them. They add 3 leading spaces to the names of the Dropbox items to make sure they come first.

**Now simply add 4 leading spaces to the Tortoise icons you would like to come first.**

Comment: The addition of a leading space to Tortoise icons helped me get rid of the issue. It is really a pity that Windows 10 OS has this restriction.

Answer (score 2):

I am not using Windows 10 nor having icon conflicts, so this may not apply to this specific question. It apply to other general tortoiseSVN icon glitches.
Before you launch your `regedit`, you can try changing icon set to another one and then go for a relaunch. If you are good, then you don't have to manually update the registry your self. 
[image]

It may not 100% apply to your case, but no harm in trying.

Comment: Nope that didn't work.  It was one of the first things I tried.  However it is Windows 10 that is broken not SVN.  The same thing happens on One Drive, on Box, etc lots of things that would like overlays to work correctly.  I only care about SVN the other things are handy but not absolutely essential.

Comment: This worked for me. Set to Win10, then restart. Icons appeared in explorer.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have Dropbox on this workstation, one of the recent Dropbox updates break TortoiseSVN's overlay icons. Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/41740663/761095 and http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4061&dsMessageId=3199988

To solve the problem, remove Dropbox or read the [FAQ](https://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#ovlnotall) and adjust Windows Registry to enable TortoiseSVN overlay icons.