# Tortoise SVN suddenly stopped showing "exclamation" icon or "differences"

Tags: android, svn

The Tortoise SVN V1.9 was working well for me with Android Studio. But today suddenly it stopped showing the "exclamation" icon on differences. Now I have no clue how to retrieve it back. Any idea? Why does this happen?

Comment: Does it show icons in Windows Explorer?

Comment: @bahrep - Nop. It vanished. This happened second time. Now I have no clue which files i made changes. Last time when same thing happened, i had to uninstall and reinstall and download copy once again from SVN. But this time if this is case, it would be really difficult time for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that Dropbox is installed on your workstation. In such case there is a great chance that TortoiseSVN overlay icons conflict with the overlay icons of Dropbox. Read [TortoiseSVN FAQ](https://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#ovlnotall).

Comment: You are a genius man @bahrep. How did u guess that! Yes, that was issue with Dropbox installed on my PC. I uninstalled, restart, and voila!! I could see the differences now. Damn! This Dropbox.

Comment: It seems that Dropbox has recently made changes that affect TortoiseSVN overlay icons (and other icons added by such tools as OneDrive at al): http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4061&dsMessageId=3199988